# Java - How to put my object in form backing in response of AJAX?

Tags: java, ajax, spring

Is there a way to put the data of formbackingObject in response of ajax? I can only put a data by using `HttpServletRespons#getWriter`, but in formbackingObject there's no instance of `HttpSerletResponse`.

Comment: From the name of the beans, I think you use `JSF`?

Comment: I don't know what you're asking. Please clarify.

Comment: In `JSF` if you want the `HttpServletResponse`, use this `HttpServletResponse resp = (HttpServletResponse) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getResponse();`